# Whats the difference between using line integral of the first kind and normal integral to find the mass of the given curve

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, line-integrals

I was working on a question that asked me to find the mass of a given curve using a specified density function. My initial approach was to use the line integral of the first kind, which intuitively seemed suitable for this question. However, upon completing the line integral, I decided to try an alternative approach using a normal double integral in polar coordinates. To my surprise, the two approaches yielded different answers.

This is the question:
Find the mass of a wire in the shape of the semi-circle
$$y = \sqrt{4 - x^2}$$ from $(2, 0)$ to $(−2, 0)$, and the density $\rho$ at a point $(x,y)$ on the wire is $\rho(x,y)=y^2$.

Approaches:

1st approach: (Line Integral of the First Kind)
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} 4 \sin^2 \theta \sqrt{(-2 \sin \theta)^2 + (2 \cos \theta)^2} \, d\theta$$

$$Result = 4\pi$$

2nd Approach: (Double Integral with Polar Coordinates)
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} r^3 \sin^2(\theta) \, d\theta \, dr$$
$$Result = 2\pi$$

Upon rechecking my calculations, I am unable to identify the source of the discrepancy between the two approaches. Aside from that, why would the double integral approach result in a lower mass compared to the line integral approach?

Comment: The two integrals don't represent the same thing. The line integral is the correct approach, while the double integral is the mass of a half-disk given density $y^2$ at every point $(x,y)$ in the region.